# ScriptLab Pivot table examples don't work anymore

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

None of the Pivot Table examples in ScriptLab work anymore in Desktop version of Excel.

For Ex, Refreshing pivot tables using

context.workbook.pivotTables.refreshAll();

throws following error.

Rich API Error, Access Denied. You cannot perform the requested operation".

However, all the samples work on Web version of Excel.

Pivot Table APIs used to work up until "Click-to-Run Version 1903. Now I have Version 1904 and the APIs are broken.

Same issue even in Version 2005 of Excel.

Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Very strange.. If i called any range functions before refreshing the pivot tables, I do not see any errors.. This find was purely accidental...

For ex, the following works..
-
-
-
context.workbook.getSelectedRange().format.autofitRows();  // call this first
context.workbook.pivotTables.refreshAll();  //now this does not throw error..

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The snippets are working for me on desktop Excel, ver 2007.

Comment: I get the following error on Excel Version 2005

c {name: "RichApi.Error", code: "AccessDenied", traceMessages: Array[0], innerError: null, debugInfo: Object}
 name: "RichApi.Error"

 code: "AccessDenied"

 traceMessages: Array[0]

 innerError: null

▶debugInfo: Object
 code: "AccessDenied"

 message: "You cannot perform the requested operation."

 toString: function ()

 errorLocation: "PivotTableCollection.add"

 statement: "var add=pivotTables.add(...);"

▶surroundingStatements: Array[9]
 0: "..."

 1: "var worksheet1=worksheets.getItem(...);"

Comment: Please see here for more details on this issue
https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/issues/820

Answer (score 0):

Office team has fixed this issue. Please see the following for complete history on this issue
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/issues/460